# Get the '_order_total_base_currency' value from the Aelia Currency Switcher and display at custom field meta-box

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, orders

I like to get the value from the Aelia Currency Switcher plugin which is the '_order_total_base_currency' and make a simple USD conversion then display it on my custom field metabox. How do I fetch that value so I can use it for calculation, and then display?

Here is my code:

```
// Adding the metabox (on the right side)
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'cdmb_add_meta_box');
function cdmb_add_meta_box() {

    add_meta_box(
        'woocommerce-order-my-custom',
        __('USD Currency display'),
        'cdmb_display_meta_box',
        'shop_order',
        'side',
        'core'
    );
}
// The metabox content
function cdmb_display_meta_box() {
    // Get

    $total_usd = (get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_order_total_base_currency', true )) / 0.75;
    $total_usd .= get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_order_total_base_currency', true );

    echo '<p>' . $total_usd . '</p>';

}

// Save/Update the meta data
add_action( 'save_post', 'cdmb_save_meta_box_data' );
function cdmb_save_meta_box_data( $post_id ) {

// Only for shop order
if ( 'shop_order' != $_POST[ 'post_type' ] )
    return $post_id;

// Checking that is not an autosave
if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
    return $post_id;

## SETTING AND UPDATING DATA ##

update_post_meta( $post_id, 'total-usd', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'total-usd' ] ) );
}

?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending time with it, I found the answer. I am now able to fetch the value for '_order_total_base_currency' from the Aelia Currency Switcher plugin.

It needs the global $post; before the variable $total_usd.

The code should be this:

```
function cdmb_display_meta_box() {
    // Get

global $post;
    $total_usd = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_order_total_base_currency', true );

    echo '<p>' . $total_usd . '</p>';
```